# Which of ieframe.dll or shdocvw.dll should be used as dependency?

Tags: vb6, dependencies, webbrowser-control, shdocvw, ieframe.dll

If I am using a `WebBrowser` component I find that sometimes the compiler will create a dependency for `ieframe.dll` and other times for `shdocvw.dll`.

Which should be used if targetting XP and Win 7?

Answer (score 1):

Since you can never redistribute either DLL it shouldn't matter.

At runtime your compiled program ought to be "finding" the required library via the compiled-in Class IDs.  These are the same no matter what version of IE is installed on target machines.

What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Are you saying that both DLLs will be present on XP/Win7 so it doesn't matter?

Comment: As I understand it the WebBrowser control "lives in" different DLLs based on the IE version (changed with 7 maybe?). But at runtime your program locates the library to use by Class ID so it shouldn't care. This same thing occurs with tons of libraries, e.g. the CDO for Windows interfaces can be in CDOSYS.DLL or in CDOEX.DLL if it is installed.